# Add ACCOUNT SETTINGS " page on Custom Site "page" on Liferay7.3.6

Tags: liferay, liferay-7, liferay-7.3

Use case:
I'm looking to add account details page on Custom site page, Right now user need to go to liferay internal site to view the user details, for which user need to leave the current site.

env:
Liferay7.3.6

[User need to click on Account Setting to see the account detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCOPA.png)

[Now User can see  all the account detail , I want this information to be on page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdYXf.png)

Recreate:
You can pull liferay7.3.6 create a test user and create a page , now we need to add the Account detail on this page, so that user does not need to go internal page.

Answer (score 1):

If you inspect the page's source code, the DOM gives you a hint of the portlet/widget that implements the "Account Settings" UI: It's `com_liferay_my_account_web_portlet_MyAccountPortlet`.

That's a widget that most likely is in a category named `category.hidden`, which, as the name implies, is not shown when you add widgets to a page. That being said, you can still do so, you'll just need to do it via the API, or change the widget's properties, which can easily be done with a standard OSGi config file.

Dave Nebinger has written about the [change of properties](https://liferay.dev/en/b/overriding-component-properties).

Without having tried it, it should be something like: Create a file `com_liferay_my_account_web_portlet_MyAccountPortlet.config`

with the content

```
com.liferay.portlet.display-category=category.sample
```

(or whatever category you'd like) and place it in your installation's osgi/configs directory.

This configuration needs to be active during your creation of the page and can be reversed after you're done - your choice if you keep it available or not.